# NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="card-id-oidc-i"]/a"}

Tags: selenium, xpath

I'm having this strange error (sometimes works sometimes does not):

> no such element: Unable to locate element:
> {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="card-id-oidc-i"]/a"}

My button has this:

```
<a href="/auth/realms/Global-Realm/broker/id-oidc-i/login?client_id=web&amp;tab_id=Doz54nelUC0&amp;session_code=gwAePmGfpQ2hBLommJO7Rswc1gNkB90Ctc4">
                                <div style="width:100%;height: 40px;">
                                <span class="arrow arrow-bar is-right"></span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="image" style="background-repeat: no-repeat;margin:auto; width:115px;height:120px"></div>
                                <div style="margin-top: 10px;min-width:170px">
                                    <h4 style="text-align:center;"><b>log in</b></h4> 
                                </div>
                                </a>
```

It's XPATH is:

```
//*[@id="card-id-oidc-i"]/a
```

I did this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"card-id-oidc-i\"]/a")).click();
```

It is strange because sometimes works just fine but sometimes it fails.

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably missing a delay.
Try using this:

```java
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30); 
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id='card-id-oidc-i']/a"))).click();
```

BTW your locator is based on some parent element with `id = card-id-oidc-i` while you shared here only the child `a` element HTML.
Also, no need to put `\` before `"` inside a String. You can simply use `'` instead as I do here.

Comment: Hey pal, i'm getting this: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: //*[@id='card-id-oidc-i']/a (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)

Comment: If so, there is no such element there or it can't be clicked. Also possibly this locator is not unique so that at least 2 elements matching `//*[@id='card-id-oidc-i']/a` while the first element is not clickable while some other can be clicked. We can't give clear answer until you share all your code

Comment: Pal, it happens when i open a session in chrome: WebDriver driver2 = new ChromeDriver();

Comment: At first it works just fine but when another session in chrome opens then it fails clicking on that button

Comment: maybe because you applying a method on wrong `driver` instance? I can only guess...

Comment: I mean: Still using `driver` where `driver2` should be used.

Answer (score 1):

`NoSuchElementException` error may occur when :

1. HTML element may not be present in a DOM yet. So you have to implement `WebDriverWait` to wait until element is present and visible in a web page.
2. HTML element may not be inside frame or iframe.

Maybe in your case it is not in the DOM yet, try to wait until it is visible and on clickable position.